# How to change the domain name for a DNN website

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

I need to change a domain name for a DNN 5 website. The customer does not want the old domain to be visible any longer so adding a portal alias does not seem to be the answer.   The site has hundreds, if not thousands, of links to files and images so I need to make sure what ever solution I use does not break this.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the new portal alias, in combination with making the requisite changes on the web server to recognize the new domain, will work.  DNN does not allow you to edit the primary portal alias through the web UI, but you could also simply update that record in the database with the new domain name (it's the PortalAlias table).

Regarding the links to files and images, if they were done as relative links then they will continue to work fine.  If the links and image urls were created with the full path, then they will have to be updated.  That could be achieved with some targeted sql scripts as well.

Comment: I agree with @Lokheed.  The Engage F3 module can help a lot with replacing an absolute urls in the site.  http://www.engagesoftware.com/Products/Modules/Engage_F3.aspx

Answer (score 2):

It's almost 10 yrs since this question was asked but I ran into this issue recently, so I'll document how I solved it. I'm using DNN version 9.1.1

1. While logged in as host/admin, go to `Site settings > Site Behavior > Site Aliases`.
2. Click `Add Alias`, and enter alias name such as **mynewurl.com**
3. Click `Set Primary` button and then `Save`.
4. Scroll to the bottom and set `Site Alias Mapping Mode` to `Redirect`. This will cause all other urls/site aliases to be redirected to the new url.
5. Finally and **VERY IMPORTANT**, open the site `web.config` and change
   the domain under `authentication` node from .myoldurl.com to
   .mynewurl.com. If you miss this step, you will not be able to login with the new url.  See below

`<authentication mode="Forms"> <forms name=".DOTNETNUKE" protection="All" timeout="60" cookieless="UseCookies" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" domain=".mynewurl.com" /> </authentication>`